# Project Format in Xcode for Building iOS Applications

Tags: xcode

The default Xcode Project Format is given to be (Xcode 9.3-compatible). What's the difference between the other Xcode project formats which includes (10.0-compatible and 11.0-compatible)and can I change the format after building my app?